# How to offer discount in auto renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, discount

Hi Apart from introductory discount is there some way by which we can offer discount to users?

Example : Say he has cancelled the subscription and his subscription is about to expire then offer him 45% discount on prices?

Solution : We can create another discounted subscription group that would have same subscription but for a lesser price. The only issue with this plan is that it may happen that a user get subscribed to two subscription gp. Also the original transaction Id changes so it will be hard to manage serve side.

Comment: There is a new system from Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/setting_up_subscription_offers